# App crashes if playlist count = 0 (Do empty playlists have a persistentid?)

Tags: ios, swift, count, playlist

My app is crashing if a playlist is empty (no songs).  My app works for all non-empty playlists.  It seems like there isn't a persistentid for an empty playlist, but I think I am wrong on that.

```
let qryPlaylists = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()
var selectedPlaylistTitle: String!
var selectedPlaylistPersistentID: UInt64!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = playlistsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let rowItem = qryPlaylists.collections![indexPath.row]

    let playlistSize = rowItem.count
    print("playlistSize = ", playlistSize)

    selectedPlaylistTitle = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as! String
    print("selectedPlaylistTitle = ", selectedPlaylistTitle)

    // Will crash on this next line if the playlistSize = 0
    selectedPlaylistPersistentID = rowItem.items[0].persistentID

    // If I use following line instead, it will crash on any playlist
    // selectedPlaylistPersistentID = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID) as! UInt64

    // This line will never be printed
    print("selectedPlaylistPersistentID = ", selectedPlaylistPersistentID)

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an array such as `items` is empty, it has no index `0` and will crash if you refer to it, with an out-of-bounds error. So if you don't want to crash, don't do that. You already know that `items` is empty, because `rowItem.count` told you so; as you said yourself, `playlistSize` is 0 in that case.

A simple-minded way to look at it is this: the largest legal index in an array is *one less* than its `count`.

---

Another issue you asked about is that this line always crashes:

```
selectedPlaylistPersistentID = rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID) as! UInt64
```

The problem here is that you are apparently using Swift 2.x. (You should have said that in your question; I deduce it, though, from the fact that `valueForProperty` has not changed to `value(forProperty:)`, which is what it is called in Swift 3.)

In Swift 2, you cannot cast directly down to UInt64. (I am surprised that the compiler does not draw your attention to this fact with a warning.) Thus, the cast fails and you crash. You need to cast down to NSNumber and then take that NSNumber's `unsignedLongLongValue`.

And while you are doing this, you really should stop using exclamation marks in your code. When I say "cast down", I mean "cast down *safely*". My own Swift 2 code for doing this sort of thing looks like this:

```
if let id = (rowItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID) as? NSNumber)?.unsignedLongLongValue {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I agree, that's a good point.  But I don't know how to stop iOS from looking at it.  In other words, elsewhere there is the call to:

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}.  That is used to fill the rows in the tableView on the screen.  Trouble is, iOS will fill the rows with playlist names regardless of weather or not they are empty.  I can't figure out how to block a row entry for an empty playlist.  Let's say I have 34 playlists and the 9th one (Classical Music, in iTunes) is empty.  That gets put in the tableView.  Game over

Comment: I don't know what you mean. "iOS" is not "looking" at anything or "filling" anything. Anything that happens is something _you_ do. This is what the word `if` is for. `if playlistSize == 0` then do _not_ say `rowItem.items[0]`. If you say it, you will crash.

Comment: Also please note that there is no need whatever to do what you are doing. An MPMediaPlaylist has a `persistentID` property of its own, even if it is empty. But that is not what you are fetching here. You are going after the wrong id.

Comment: Thank you!  I am somewhat new to iOS and Swift.  It makes sense that a persistentID exists for empty playlists.  So, my code is wrong!  Can you please tell me how to properly fetch the persistentID of a playlist?  I would really appreciate it.  I was thinking that the commented out line that includes MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID would do it, but that crashes too.  Thanks again for you time!

Comment: Okay, that appears to be because you are saying `as! UInt64`, which will always crash in Swift 2.x. Added an explanation of how to extract a UInt64 in Swift 2.x. Next time, please be specific about what version of Swift you are using (or, even better, update to Swift 3).

Comment: Matt, thank you very much for the help!  I may not have the chance to change the code today, but I will by tomorrow.  Yes, I am using Swift 2.x and Xcode 7.3.1, I will mention that next time.  I had gone up on the App Store and there were several bad reviews on the new Xcode, so I was waiting a bit.  Plus, being new to Swift, I wasn't sure how much of my code (if any) would have to be rewritten.  Guess I wanted to get the bulk of my main ideas done before I switched.

Comment: "and there were several bad reviews on the new Xcode" Ridiculous. This is _far_ and away the best version of Xcode there has ever been. "I wasn't sure how much of my code (if any) would have to be rewritten" All of it. Swift 3 is a very different language, not least because of "renamification" of methods. If you are learning Swift by using Swift 2, in my opinion you've made a very regrettable decision. I strongly urge you to switch immediately to Swift 3 (where you _can_ cast down to UInt64!).

Comment: Your suggestions solved it!  Thanks again for all of your help.  I had decided to start learning Swift (on a part-time basis) before version 3 was released.  I will upgrade to the newer Xcode/Swift soon.  Thanks again.